# Using the definition of a manifold directly prove that the $2$-sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a $C^\infty$-manifold of dimension $2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Using the definition of a manifold directly prove that the $2$-sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a $C^\infty$-manifold of dimension $2$.

[Hint:  one way (though certainly not the only way) to do this is to
try stereographic projections (draw a straight line from the north pole to the $z = −1$ plane and assign the point that intersects the sphere the corresponding point that intersects the $z= 1$ plane,then do something analogous for the south pole and the $z= 1$ plane)

I drew what the hint said and now I am wondering what to do next. How should i go about this?

Definition of a manifold: A subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is an $m-$ dimensional manifold iff for all $c\in M$ there exists $U,V \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and a diffeomorphism $U \rightarrow \psi ^{\leftarrow \phi} V$ such that $c \in U$ and $\phi(U \cap M)= (\mathbb{R}^m \times {0}\}\cap V$

My drawing looks something like:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#/media/File:Stereographic_projection_in_3D.svg

Where $(0,0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is the north pole and $(0,0,-1)$ is the south pole.

Comment: Ignore the hint if you can think of another way to obtain a smooth atlas.

Comment: I was going to write an answer, but that hint does almost all of the job, so if you don't understand that then you'll probably not understand any other answer.

Comment: Explaining the hint would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I drew what the hint said and now I am wondering what to do next

Comment: Should my picture look like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#/media/File:Stereographic_projection_in_3D.svg

Comment: @AlexM. I am still trying to figure this out using the hint.